# Does Taiwanese accent pronounce 他 as hā or am I hearing the end of tā?

Tags: pronunciation, taiwan

Watching [A Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Sun_(film)) (Taiwanese drama, available on Netflix) it sounds to me like the characters are saying 他 as hā. This seems to be true even when people aren't speaking particularly quickly. Am I hearing a regional pronunciation, or is that just the *end* of tā without the plosive (*plosive* is the very first part of the T sound where the air stops)?

Comment: Are there any YouTube, etc. clips that can be heard for reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the pronunciation of 他 can be written as ㄊㄚ in Zhuyin. And ㄊ is plosive pronunciation. So the answer is no.

Comment: Is your answer based on what people ought to say or how people actually speak in the drama? I haven't watched it, but considering that the other person who answered also thinks it sounds abbreviated is interesting! I think we all know that the standard pronunciation in Taiwan is with an aspirated plosive, but that's not what the question is about! Just to be clear, I haven't watched the drama in question, it just strikes me that your answer seems to be based on how the sound is written normally (which is of course correct). What specific people say might be different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm watching the same movie and they're definitely saying ha1. Taiwanese shorten a lot of words, for example da1 jia1 becomes da1 a1.